# Simplifiying $A \cos(x-\phi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to proof that we can transform this expression : $$a \cos x + b \sin x$$
to this one :  $$A \cos (x-\phi)$$

Indeed, I can do the reverse path using the formula of $\cos(x-y)= \cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y$

but I get stuck on the initial path.

Which trig formula should I use?

Thanks

Comment: Yes the formula is correct, let plug in the values!

Comment: This is correct for the reverse path,  how can I transform a cos x + b sin x ?

Comment: Start with $A\cos(x-\phi)$.

Comment: I can't start with this, I have to comme to this.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
\begin{align*}
A\cos(x-\phi)&=A\cos x\cos \phi+A\sin x\sin \phi\\
&=(A\cos \phi)\cos x+(A\sin \phi)\sin x\\
&=a\cdot \cos x+ b\cdot \sin x
\end{align*}
where $a=A\cos \phi$ and $b=A\sin \phi$

Now, let us try to solve the equations
$$a=A\cos \phi\\ b=A\sin \phi$$

Squaring the equations and adding them, we get
$$a^2+b^2=A^2\cos^2\phi+A^2\sin^2\phi=A^2\left(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\right)=A^2$$
which gives
$$A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Put this back into the first equation and see that
$$a=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos \phi$$
which means
$$\phi=\cos^{-1}\frac a {\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

So, we have proved that given the expression
$$a\cos x+b\sin x$$
we can write it as
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos\left(x-\cos^{-1}\frac a {\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$
which gives you the required form.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not respond to my questions  I have to proof that there existe a two reals $A >0$ et $\phi$ that verify the equality

Comment: @ZchGarinch You can just follow the proof bottom to top, you also need to show that the equations $a=A\cos \phi, b=A\sin\phi$ have a solution for all $a,b$, as a possible hint to that $a^2+b^2=A^2$.

Comment: @ZchGarinch oh, you wanted the reverse path? Sorry, I didn't see it. Wait, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @ZchGarinch Please check the edit. Is it okay now?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with
$$a \cos x + b \sin x
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow a\cdot \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} + b\cdot \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}
$$

$$\Longrightarrow \frac{e^{ix}(2ia+2b) -e^{-ix}(-2ia+2b)}{4i}$$

$$\Longrightarrow \frac{Me^{ix}e^{i\theta} -Me^{-ix}e^{-i\theta}}{4i}$$
where $M=\sqrt{4a^2+4b^2}$ , $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b})$ then

$$\Longrightarrow\frac{M\sin(x+\theta)}{2}$$

It can be seen as
$$\Longrightarrow A\cos(x-\phi)$$

where $A=\frac{M}{2}$ and  $\phi=-\theta+\pi$

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed with your initial path as follows

$$a\cos x +b\sin  x$$

Multiply and divide by $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x +\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin  x)$$

Now $(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})^2+(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})^2=1$ and both terms are less than $1$

Therefore if we let one as $\cos \phi $ other can be let us $\sin \phi$

Therefore we have

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\cos\phi\cos x + \sin\phi\sin x)$$

$$A\cos (\phi-x)$$

Thus there exists two reals $A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\phi= \cos^{-1}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})$ for which $a\cos x +b\sin  x$ is identically equal to $A\cos (\phi-x)$